# Storing and echoing php code in db

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have been trying to test this out. I put in the code below in the database.

```
  <?php

   $test = "Whats up";

   print $test;

   ?>
```

And then on a page i do select and then i try to echo but it won't do it unless i rid the entry of the start and end tags.  So if i wanted to execute this php by calling it from the db, how would i do it? Thanks.

Comment: Please add more context. And what do you mean by "calling code from the database"? That is usually a bad practice, and there is likely to be a better solution. What do you need to do that for?

Comment: It is never a good idea to put code into the database. Code **should be stored in the filesystem**, without any exceptions.

Comment: I am storing the html for the website and the PHp coding.

Comment: @pekka i am putting in php coding to serve customized options and content.  This is the way i thought it would work out.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [eval](http://php.net/eval) to treat a string as runnable PHP code, for example:

```
<?php
$string = 'echo "hello";';
eval($string);
?>
```

As Pekka suggests, this is bad practice and you should probably rethink your solution. There's hardly ever motivated to store code in the database (the database is for *data*).

Comment: I am new so i thought using the db as a storage space for code is the way to dybamically serve code.  Right now i ahve html pasted on every single page, i thought using the db i can update it once and echo every where.  So i thought i could also do customizations and updates using this method.  If this is not safe then when else can i do? Thanks!

Comment: The database is mainly for storing data, for example the raw texts for each page. Themes and other code parts are often saved as files on disk. Perhaps the biggest reason to avoid eval is the dangers involved in letting users arbitrarily run PHP code - by only allowing PHP to be run from files you get the safety provided by the FTP server and doesn't have to worry about such stuff while writing your web code.

Comment: So i am doing it the right way then by pasting the html onto each page and then just using the php.

Comment: And why is this dangerous? Users will not be updating this.  Only i will put stuff in the tables.

Comment: In this case would it better to use include() function and do the customized options and features...

Comment: If users won't be updating it, there could be a point in saving to the database, but note that database access generally is slower than file access and that you still will need to take extra precautions against crackers.

Comment: should i use the include() function for custom requirements.  i can do the php routing/verification and then show another page...?

Comment: I don't know anything about your code or what design patterns you have chosen, but the include function may be one possibility here, yes. Maybe even better is require, which terminates the script on inclusion failure.

Answer (score 1):

you could use serialize - unserialize function to save object or variable. and you can use [eval](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function to run code

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is exactly what I was looking for. We have CMS deployed accross multiple servers and in order to maintain the base functions (without the need to make a url based include of our main functions file) it was easier to store and call these functions from our group=wide single database. We use medium blob and store a serialized base_64 encoded text file there.

So to serialize the code we use this script without the php tags:

```
<form name="serialise_script" action="" method="post" >
    <p>Put Script in here (without php tags???)</p>
    <textarea cols="100" rows="25" name="serializeme" ></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="go" />
</form>

<?php if(isset($_POST['serializeme'])){
    echo "<p>Your Code</p><textarea style='border:3px solid black;padding:0.5em;' cols='100' rows='25' >" . base64_encode(serialize($_POST['serializeme'])) . "</textarea>";
 } ?>
```

Then copy the script and paste the output code into a text file.
Upload that to the medium blob table

Then to output again from the database and set to a session variable... I just did this:

```
eval(unserialize(base64_decode($_SESSION['functions'])));
```

But it was the eval bit I needed to make it work. By serializing and encoding means we shouldn't have any problems.

Now all I need to do is manage 1 base code for many sites across certain servers. AKA One bug fix would solve all issues across all deployments.

Thanks

Andi